# Execute Same Jenkins job "N" number of times based on the value received for parameter "N "

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Execute Same Jenkins job N number of times based on the value received for parameter N

Comment: Could you please specify your question. where does the parameter come from? what do you want to do? This is to less informations to answer your question. Please provide a more detailed example of the jenkins job you planned.

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities :

1. From your calling script, do a loop that will call the same Jenkins job `N` times (e.g. using Jenkins REST API to call your job).
2. Call your job once with an integer parameter `N` and inside your pipeline job just add a for loop that will loop `N` times, and do whatever treatment you need to do `N` times in this for loop (e.g. calling another function)

Comment: Thanks for the update but i want to call jobs in parallel like below but now it is not working and getting the below message.            buildClosures = []
for (int i=1; i<3; i++) {
    def curClosure = {
        def j = i
        build("Test1", Parameter: j)
    }
    buildClosures.add(curClosure)
}

// execute the closures in buildClosures in parallel
parallel(buildClosures)                                                                                                                    but i am getting the error illegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got

Answer (score 0):

Running same job in parallel means they all use same workspace, in most loop kind of execution.

## SOLUTION: Use MultiJob, with all jobs in same phases.

1. Clone same job, in needed number of instances (i.e N=3) that need to be executed in parallel.
2. Create MultiJob with just one phase
3. Set all 3 jobs in same phase in MultiJob, and all of them will run in parallel.

Comment: Only bad part about this is cloning. That seems a bit unnecessary. For 3 it would work. What if the N=500?

Comment: Good point @hiquetj  Nature of the problem and needed info will "say" 
which type of parallelism is most suitable.  
In example:    1. If I need something _500 times, with summarized report only_ (such as performance tests), I **prefer loops** to do it through code. Multi threading is the answer, with all boundaries such as shared resources, etc.    2. If I need report, results, or some action on the end of iteration on up to i.e. 10 parallel jobs, I might use job cloning as fast and safe solution.